# Display item in Jlist Swing in ordered manner

Tags: java, swing, jlist

I want the data to be displayed orderly i.e AAAA ZZZZ AKH should be one below the other.

I used Jlist to display it.

My code used to display is:

```
    class Pojo {
    private String case_no;     
    private String reffered;
    private String time;
    public Pojo(String case_no, String reffered,String time) {
       this.case_no = case_no;       
       this.reffered = reffered;
       this.time = time;   
    }
    public String getId() {
        return case_no;
    }
    public String getReferred() {
        return reffered;
    }
     public String getTime() {
        return time;
    }    
    public String toString() {
        return MessageFormat.format("{0} {1} {2}", 
                getId(),
                getReferred(),
                getTime());
    }
    }
```

```
OUTPUT:
----------------------------
D8 AAA 17/09/2014 16:39:40
D9 ZZZ 17/09/2014 16:49:40
D10 AKH 17/09/2014 17:59:40
D13 AAAA 19/09/2014 17:59:40
-----------------------------
```

Comment: *"I want .."* ..a question.  Do you have one?

Comment: BTW - given the data, I'm thinking a `JTable` would better display it.

Comment: But I want whole row to be selected which I cant do it in JTable

Comment: _" I want whole row to be selected which I cant do it in JTable"_ Who says? `table.getSelectionModel().addListSelectionListener(...)`.

Comment: See [How to use Tables: User Selections](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#selection)... `table.getSelectedRow()` will get you a whole row

Answer (score 0):

Your data and the output you want simply begs for a `JTable` instead of a `JList`:

- The columns will be nicely aligned like you asked
- If needed, you can offer the user the ability to order the data on each of the columns, which will be near impossible to offer in an intuitive way on the `JList`
- If needed, you can offer the user the ability to display only certain columns and hide other ones

If you only want to allow selection of a whole row, you just need to indicate this to the table. Use

- [`JTable#setCellSelectionEnabled( false )`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JTable.html#setCellSelectionEnabled-boolean-)
- [`JTable#setColumnSelectionEnabled( false )`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JTable.html#setColumnSelectionAllowed-boolean-)
- [`JTable#setRowSelectionEnabled( true )`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JTable.html#setRowSelectionAllowed-boolean-)